# Softlayer API Hardware data retrieval

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a question regarding the information provided by API key for hardware and devices provided by Softlayer.

For example for ESXi device Softlayer API provides a Serial Number of C......, while our script provides a Serial Number (hsSerial) of E....... for that same device. When we look in the VMWare console directly, we see both of those values listed as "Service Tags". We are wondering what is the difference between these two values? and is there another field in the Softlayer API that would return value E....... for same ESXi device?

Comment: and how are you getting that serial number via API?

Comment: Via SLAM tool created to build Softlayer inventory using API.